# Send webservices result to the view through the viewmodel

Tags: web-services, xaml, mvvm, windows-phone-8, command

I'm creating my first windows phone 8 application and I want to login so I created a LoginViewModel with a LoginModel than in my MainPage.xaml I was binding the login button with the command in the LoginViewModel where the webservice call happens like this

```
public class LoginDataViewModel
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    private LoginDataINPC _loginDataData { get; set; }

    private string _username {get;set; }
    private string _password { get; set; }

    private ICommand _loginCommand;

    public LoginDataViewModel()
    {
        this._loginCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.LoginAction);
        _loginDataData = new LoginDataINPC();
    }

    public ICommand LoginCommand 
    {
        get 
        {
            return this._loginCommand;
        }
    }

    public LoginDataINPC DataSource 
    {
        get { return _loginDataData; }
        set 
        { 
            _loginDataData = value;
        }
    }

    private void LoginAction(object p)
    {
        AuthenticateUsernamePasswordRequest request = new AuthenticateUsernamePasswordRequest();

        request.UserName = _loginDataData.UserName;
        request.Password = _loginDataData.Password;

        CompanyUIServiceClient client = new CompanyUIService.CompanyUIServiceClient();

        client.AuthenticateUsernamePasswordCompleted += client_AuthenticateUsernamePasswordCompleted;
        client.AuthenticateUsernamePasswordAsync(request);

    }

    void client_AuthenticateUsernamePasswordCompleted(object sender, CompanyUIService.AuthenticateUsernamePasswordCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result != null)
        {
            CompanyUIService.AuthenticateUsernamePasswordResponse response = new AuthenticateUsernamePasswordResponse();
            try
            {
                response = e.Result;

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                response = null;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            CompanyUIService.AuthenticateUsernamePasswordResponse response = null;
        }


    }
```

I was debugging this and the webservice call is working but my problem is how to send the result to the view (MainPage.xaml) so it will either show me an error message popup or a redirect to the next view ?

Comment: How are you triggering the LoginCommand or otherwise binding the VM to the view?

Comment: You need to bind the response in VM with View

Answer (score 0):

In MVVM the ViewModel should not communicate with the View directly. The ViewModel should not know about the view. What the ViewModel can do is send messages to anybody interested. The View can subscribe to those messages and react on them. In my example I'm using [MVVM Light](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/). This is a very lightweight class library and works like a charm.

What you need to do is define a message that the ViewModel will send. Something like:

```
public class LoginMessage 
{
  public CompanyUIService.AuthenticateUsernamePasswordResponse Response { get; set; }
}
```

Your ViewModel can then broadcast this message like so:

```
void client_AuthenticateUsernamePasswordCompleted(
  object sender, 
  CompanyUIService.AuthenticateUsernamePasswordCompletedEventArgs e)
{
  // your code here
  var message = new LoginMessage { Response = response };
  Messenger.Default.Send<LoginMessage>( message );
}
```

In your View you subscribe to the messages in the constructor or the Load event like so:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<LoginMessage>( 
  this, 
  ( action ) => HandleLoginMessage( action ) );
```

In the HandleLoginMessage you can do whatever you want to do:

```
private object HandleLoginMessage( LoginMessage message )
{
  // do whatever you like
}
```